# Splitting dash separated values in power bi without replicating other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

[image]

Hi;
I have this data in excel file and I want to split the dash separated values into different rows within the same cell (splitting the dash separated values cell only).

I want to count the total credit hours for each SP & WD without replicating the credit hours, How can I do that in Power bi and Excel?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Comma (,)?? I think you wanted to say dash (-)?

Comment: Yes, dash separated values

Comment: It's not helpful to provide sample data as jpg.

Comment: How can I attach the excel file?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You should model this as two separate tables.

The basic approach here is to have two copies of the query.  One where you remove SP, eg Course(Course Name, Credit hours, WD), and a second one like CourseSP(Course Name, SP).  Then in the second one you can split SP to rows without duplicating Credit Hours.  Then in your Datamodel create a 1-many relationship between Course and CourseSP.

Comment: Would have been my approach too.

Answer (score 1):

You question is not clear.  If there are three items in the SP row, does the 4 credit hours get applied to each one individually, or do 1/3 of the credit hours get applied to each one individually? Below is a powerquery method for doing both of those, and grouping by SP. You could also group by WD or by both WD and SP by changing the group

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Course", type text}, {"Credit Hours", Int64.Type}, {"WD", Int64.Type}, {"SP", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Split([SP]," - ")),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "ProratedCreditHours", each [Credit Hours]/List.Count([Custom])),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom"}, {{"Prorate Credit Hours", each List.Sum([ProratedCreditHours]), type number}, {"Credit Hours", each List.Sum([Credit Hours]), type nullable number}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Note if you really just want to break out SP onto lines within a row, just do a replace on the dash with a break. Your choice of **#(lf)** or **#(cr)**
That would not help on summing or grouping

Comment: Nice workaround. In DAX you would use UNICHAR(10) to add line breaks.